# Use show or shown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using below JavaScript code. Instead of hidden. i want if div is visible then hide it on page load. on button click it should be visible. but current it is doing the opposite.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lnkbtn").click(function () {
           if ($('#divreg').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#divreg').show(500);
                document.getElementById('lnkbtn').innerHTML = "Hide";
            } else {
                $("#divreg").hide(500);
                document.getElementById('lnkbtn').innerHTML = "Show";

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
   <asp:Button ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" Text="Additional Details" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return false;"  />
   <div id="divreg">
     <p> Some content here.. </p>
   </div>
```

Comment: show your html code or make a fiddle.

Comment: since you are alredy using jQuery for part of the code -  why not use $('#lnkbtn').html('Hide')? or  $('#lnkbtn').text('Hide')

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pqho3tvg/3/

Answer (score 0):

in your fiddle, you are using `"display:none"` as the css to hide the div, but you are checking for is using `:hidden` which means that it will never test true; you need to change the css to `"visibility:hidden"` and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqho3tvg/3/).

You can hide it on `load` of jquery, check if it is visible hide it:

```
if ($('#divreg').is(":visible")) {
  $("#divreg").hide();
}
```

Then on your `click` event perform hide/show:

```
$("#lnkbtn").click(function() {
  if ($('#divreg').is(":hidden")) {
    $('#divreg').show(500);
    $('#lnkbtn').val("Hide");
  } else {
    $("#divreg").hide(500);
    $('#lnkbtn').val("Show");

  }

});
```